# Post reboot of RHEL6.3 is not working

Tags: linux, administrator

I configured RAID 0 on IBM System X server and tried installing RHEL6.3 but after installing the packages once it reboots it wont be able to complete the installation(stuck @ grub loader each time). I tried with RAID1 as well but no luck.
I initialized all disks during both the configuration (RAID 0 and 1) but no +ve result.

Seems like its not able to get MBR. Currently its EFI partion system . If I do installs RHEL6.2 it works fine. I dont want to do a upgrade I want to do fresh installation.

Any help appreciated.

-Pankaj

Comment: What's wrong with installing from 6.2 media and updating online to 6.3?